How to run async playwright?
I'm trying to control the adspower anti-detect browser's API with playwright.
import requests
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

ads_id='kkvlbud'
response = requests.get("http://local.adspower.com:50325/api/v1/browser/start?user_id=" + ads_id).json()
ws_url = response['data']['ws']['puppeteer']

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.connect_over_cdp(ws_url)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('google.com')

Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
Please use the Async API instead.

To run playwright in async, use the asnyc api. See the official documention for examples: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-playwright
